# Cannot got to definition , in my vscode using robotframework

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automation, robotframework, function-definition

I am trying to use robotframework with vscode and installed robotframework language server , i am not able to jump to function definition .

expected response :- should jump to function definition when i click the cntrl+left mouse click .
response got : - No response

in my .vscode i only have launch.json .
Any dependency i am missing?
dependencies installed :- python3 , robotframework , pip , sshlibrary , requestslibrary

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: it was not going to definition and not showing the suggestions even if robo framework was intalled

Answer (score 2):

It should be `Alt + left mouse click`. In addition, the shortcut key should be `F12`.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_navigation*

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics*

Comment: tried this didnt help

Comment: Please update your question instead of just saying it is useless.    Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install these extensions:

`Robot Framework Language Server`

`Robocorp Code`

`Robotframework debugger`

Then, reload the VScode window  and try again.

Comment: Tried this didnt help